# How to lift state in react

Tags: reactjs, use-state, swiper.js

I'm struggling with the tutorial of React on how to lift a state. I have built the following:

After learning how to pass a state to a child, I am now wondering how to do it between children.

Parent:

```
const PostTemplate = ({ data }) => {
  const [isIndex, setIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
        <Slider
          setIndex={isIndex}
          {...data}
        />
        <Views
          setIndex={setIndex}
          {...data}
        />
    </>
  );
};
```

Child1 (Views):

```
const Views = ({views, setIndex}) => {
  return (
      <div>
        {views.edges.map(({ node: view }, index) => (
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setIndex(index);
            }}
          >
            <p>Hello</p>
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Child2 (Slider):

```
const Slider = ({views, isIndex}) => {
  return (
      <Swiper initialSlide={isIndex}>
        {views.edges.map(({ node: view }) => (
          <SwiperSlide>Slide</SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
  );
};
```

I would like to do is pass the index of the click “Views” element to the `initialSlide` prop of the Slider. Right now, this only returns a rather strange error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'el.classList')`.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: try `data` prop with `({ data })` instead of `( data )` on child1-2) and where is `setIndex` props you are passing from child to parent?

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov what do you mean by “where is setIndex props you are passing from child to parent”? setIndex is first set in the parent. When one of the elements is clicked in the child (Views) it should pass its index to child (Slider).

Comment: in that case, you are gonna use `Views props={props}` inside `Slider`

Comment: @MukhriddinShakhriyorov where should I do that? initialSlide={isIndex} where isIndex should be the index of the clicked item in Views. I am passing setIndex from parent to Views and isIndex from parent to Slider. In Views I do onclick setIndex(index). Somewhere in this might be an error? But then, I'd like to pass the index to Slider with initialSlide={isIndex}.